# How to pass const struct pointer to a setter method in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to pass a const struct pointer to a setter `setContainer` of an auto-generated C++ API code so I can't change the class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Class // Class definition
{
public:
    struct Container    // Container definition
    {
        double value = 0.0;
    };

    Class() { } // constructor
    ~Class() { } // destructor

    void setContainer(const Container * pContainer)
    {   
        mContainer = *pContainer; // setter
    }

    const Class::Container & getContainer() const
    {
        return mContainer; // getter
    }

private:
    Container mContainer;
};
```

As you can see I don't know how to pass the struct object to `setContainer` method in the correct manner. Smart pointers would be even better as I am using C++14.

```
int main()
{    
    Class objClass; 

    const auto container1 = objClass.getContainer();

    // Output: container1.value: 0.0
    std::cout << "container1.value: " << container1.value << std::endl; 
    
    // Need to set this at runtime
    Class::Container container2;
    container2.value = 5.0; 

    // Output: container2.value: 5.0
    std::cout << "container2.value: " << container2.value << std::endl; 
    
    // ERROR: no matching function for call to ‘Class::setContainer(Class::Container&)’
    objClass.setContainer(container2); 
    
    const auto container3 = objClass.getContainer();

    // Desired Output: container3.value: 5.0 (set by setContainer)
    std::cout << "container3.value: " << container3.value << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

I'd really appreciate some help getting this right.

Comment: You might even consider not using any pointers at all. 
void setContainer(const Container& container) will be even more safe. 
(you can't put nullptr's in references)

Comment: Change `void setContainer(const Container * pContainer)` to `void setContainer(Container const& pContainer)`.  Otherwise, you'll also want to check for nullptr, and the caller will have to pass in the address of a Container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setter function expects a pointer to a `Container` object, so give it one: just add the [`&` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) to your argument:

```cpp
    objClass.setContainer(&container2);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use smart pointer and get() function to extract raw pointer as below

```
std::shared_ptr<Class::Container>m_container2 = std::make_shared<Class::Container>(container2);
 objClass.setContainer(m_container2.get());
```

or you can use & operator to get the pointer.